# Short symmetric formula for 'at most one of P, Q, and R is true'?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Just now I discovered that
$$
\text{at most one of } P, Q, R \text{ is true}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
((P \equiv Q) \land (Q \not\equiv R)) \:\:\equiv\:\: R
$$
I like this, but I don't like the loss of symmetry.  Is there perhaps another fairly short, but more symmetric, equivalent formula?

(As inspiration, note that
$$
\text{exactly one of } P,Q,R \text{ is true}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
(P \equiv Q \equiv R) \;\land\; \lnot(P \land Q \land R)
$$
which is nicely symmetric, since both $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\land\;$ are symmetric and associative.)

Comment: The formula $(P \equiv Q) \land (Q \not\equiv R) \:\equiv\: R$ needs parentheses.

Comment: @GitGud I always follow Dijkstra's convention of letting $\land$ and $\lor$ have precedence over $\equiv$: it saves on parentheses, and spacing helps to remove any remaining doubt.  Still, I'm adding parentheses for clarity.

Comment: $(P \equiv Q \equiv R) \;\land\; \lnot(P \land Q \land R)$ does not work. 
Let $P \equiv 1, Q \equiv R \equiv 0$:
$[(1 \equiv 0 \equiv 0) \land \lnot (1 \land 0 \land 0)] = [0 \equiv 1] = [0] $

Comment: @Trismegistos I think that is not correct: $[(1 \equiv 0 \equiv 0) \land \lnot (1 \land 0 \land 0)] = [1 \land \lnot 0] = [1]$.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster $1 \equiv 0 \equiv  0$ is 0 not 1. Probably formula should look like this:
$\lnot (P \equiv Q \equiv R) \;\land\; \lnot(P \land Q \land R)$

Comment: @Trismegistos I'm sorry, but $[(1 \equiv 0) \equiv 0] = [0 \equiv 0] = 1$ and also $[1 \equiv (0 \equiv 0)] = [1 \equiv 1] = 1$ (since $\equiv$ is associative).  Why do you think this expression is $0$?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster I thought $A \equiv B \equiv C$ means that all A, B, C have same value analogous to $A=B=C$ for normal equality symbol.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster According to Wolfram Alpha $A \equiv B \equiv C$ is true when all three are true or all tree are false. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p+%3C%3D%3E+q+%3C%3D%3E+c

Comment: @Trismegistos OK, I did not intend this alternate reading; apologies for any misunderstanding.  Blame Dijkstra et al.'s influence on my mathematical notations and thinking. :-)  Oh, and I've given feedback to Wolfram|Alpha that they should tell the user about this ambiguity.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster If you get some answer from Wolfram please share in this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lnot[(P\land Q)\lor(Q\land R)\lor(R\land P)]
$$
$$
(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)\land(\lnot Q\lor\lnot R)\land(\lnot R\lor\lnot P)
$$

Comment: +1 I really like this one. I'll mark this one if there is no better answer in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I found another short equivalent, which is slightly more symmetric than my original:
$$
\color{lightgray}((P \equiv R) \lor (Q \equiv R)\color{lightgray}) \;\not\equiv\; R \\
\color{lightgray}((P \not\equiv R) \land (Q \not\equiv R)\color{lightgray}) \;\equiv\; R \\
$$
But I'm adding this one more for completeness...